# PLSQL Conditional rules

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, sqlplus

Conditional rules required:

```
IF 
A then currency = ABC
B then currency = ABD
C then currency = ABE
NULL = Returns data from A, B and C but it's currency is ABC
```

Trying to implement this logic, I've tried to use 3 separate CASE statements but this doesn't appear to work. Any helps appreciated

What i currently have:

(Tried a few variations)

```
 CASE
             WHEN '&SITE' IS 'A' THEN
                COJ.CURRENCY_CODE IS 'ABC'
         END A,
         CASE
             WHEN '&SITE' IS 'B' THEN
                COJ.CURRENCY_CODE IS 'ABD'
         END B,
         CASE
             WHEN '&SITE' IS NULL 'C' THEN
                COJ.CURRENCY_CODE IS 'ABE'
         END C,
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask]. Please decide if you are using SQL Server or Oracle since they are two different products using two different sql dialects, and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: It might help to have a bit more context, especially in terms of returns all

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so that we don't repeat?

Comment: Sorry, if NULL then all the data from A B and C will return but currency will be ABC

Comment: @JonTout Updated

Comment: your requirement is still not clear in your case statement you are comparing two string values  WHEN '&SITE' IS 'B'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [decode function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) for if statement, only B and C produce different value then default:

```
 decode(x, 'B', 'ABD', 'C', 'ABE','ABC')
```

Comment: @mfgn use it as is after `COJ.CURRENCY_CODE IS ` or `COJ.CURRENCY_CODE = `

Answer (score 2):

You should stick with the `case` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN '&SITE' = 'A' THEN 'ABC'
      WHEN '&SITE' = 'B' THEN 'ABD'
      WHEN '&SITE' = 'C' THEN 'ABE'
      ELSE 'ABC'
 END) as currency_code
```

Or:

```
(CASE '&SITE' WHEN 'A' THEN 'ABC'
              WHEN 'B' THEN 'ABD'
              WHEN 'C' THEN 'ABE'
              ELSE 'ABC'
 END) as currency_code
```

`CASE` is standard SQL and available in all databases and most people find it much clearer.  `DECODE()` is bespoke Oracle code implemented before they went with the standard function.  `CASE` has been available in Oracle for 20 years.

Comment: Works perfectly, using this now. Thanks alot